# Парсинг с помощью XPath

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="ra-elements-list__section ra-elements-list__section_pay">
<div class="ra-elements-list__pay">Пример</div>
<div class="ra-elements-list__extra" style="display: none">
<div class="ra-elements-list__meta">Текст1<br/>Текст2<br/>Текст3<br/>Текст4
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Как вытащить именно инфу с первого div в

```
ra-elements-list__section ra-elements-list__section_pay
```

пробую вот так

```
HtmlNodeCollection money = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'ra-elements-list__section ra-elements-list__section_pay')]/div[1]");
```

ничего не парсит

Comment: может div(0)? ты программировать умеешь? елемент проверил?

Comment: а может div(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуй

```
.//div[@class='ra-elements-list__section']/div[1]
```

Comment: @while, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: а не подскажете как поочередно извлечь из
<div class="ra-elements-list__meta">Текст1<br/>Текст2<br/>Текст3<br/>
Текст1, Текст2, Текст3?

Comment: Получить как строку и разбить по сепаратору